# Third if-clause can't be reached

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

This probably has an easy solution, but I simply don't see it at the moment.
I have three if-clauses that ashould be activated based on the length of an array. The first two ones seem to work fine, but for some odd reason I can't activate the third one (arr.length === 3). Right before the if clauses I have tried an alert to test whether it gives the right length of the array and it does.

```
function calculateDistances() {
        var arr = [];

        arr.push(posM, posL, posR);
        alert(arr[1])
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (!arr[i]) {
                arr.splice(i,1)
            }
        }
        alert(arr.length)
        if (arr.length === 0 || 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (arr.length === 2 ) {
            var diameter = calculateDiameter(arr[0], arr[1])
            if (diameter > minDistance) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (arr.length === 3) {
            alert("hello")
            var diameter1 = calculateDiameter(arr[0], arr[1]);
            var diameter2 = calculateDiameter(arr[0], arr[2]);
            var diameter3 = calculateDiameter(arr[1], arr[3]);

            if (diameter1 && diameter2 && diameter3 < minDistance) {
                return true
            }
            else{
                return false
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `arr.length === 0 || 1` is always true.

Comment: I think that's a wrong approach you will never reach the third if anyway

Answer (score 7):

Nor can you activate the second.

There's a bug here: `if (arr.length === 0 || 1) {`

The `1` casts to `true`.

Perhaps you meant: `if (arr.length === 0 || arr.length === 1) {`

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
if (arr.length === 0 || arr.length === 1) {
```

The way you put it, it is equal to

```
if ((arr.length === 0) || true) {
```

which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is below condition in the first if condition

```
if (arr.length === 0 || arr.length === 1) {
            return true;
  }
```

this checks whether the length of the array is 1 or it's 0. Your first if condition is always true as it has `1` which is true.

Comment: You are welcome .. Can you mark this as answer if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
(arr.length === 0 || 1)
```

is always true.

You could usethis instead

```
if (arr.length <= 1)
{
    return true;
}
```